# Customizing Symfony 2 embedded form prototype

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to customize embedded form prototype in my small project. I have read short description on [symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype) on how to do this, but at this moment I am only 50% successful. After widget definition as described in symfony's docs, single row on existing record renders correctly using my template. But prototype is still default.

Here is widget definition:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _refuel_form_fuels_entry_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <table class="form-table compact">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ form_label(form.fuel) }}</th>
                <td>
                    {{ form_errors(form.fuel) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.fuel) }}
                </td>
                <th>{{ form_label(form.currencyRatio) }}</th>
                <td>
                    {{ form_errors(form.currencyRatio) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.currencyRatio) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            ... other rows ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

And with this code I am rendering rows for existing records (edit form):

```
<tr>
    <th>{{ form_label(form.fuels) }}</th>
    <td colspan="3">
        <ul class="fuels collection-holder" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.fuels.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
            {% for fuel in form.fuels %}
                <li>
                    {{ form_row(fuel) }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, symfony know I want to use custom template for each subform, but why it still is not using it for prototype generation? Do I have to enable that widget somehow to work with prototype? There is no such info in docs.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just realized where problem is minute after posting question. My template "overrides" `_row` block which corresponds to `form_row` function as used in for loop. But in prototype attribute I left copied code from docs which uses `form_widget` function... See the problem? Yup. Changed attribute to: `data-prototype="{{ form_row(form.fuels.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"` and boom! Prototype generated correctly. Stupid me...